# Pausing script 3M keyboard wedge XML

Tags: javascript, xml, scripting, notepad++, keyboard-wedge

I am using a device called 3m cr100m,which can be used to enter data from passport and so on.
I am running the below script but would like to pause after a certain Data Handler until i press a certain key such as ctrl+W or something of similar.

The application I am using it for is 2 page based.

First page has name,gender and date of birth and some data to be typed manually then click next,second page has passport number,issue date and expiration date.

Below is my code for 3m cr100m using program called keyboard wedge which loads the below mentioned script, the script is in xml file and is meant for a little bit of data handling only from what I can understand.

IF of any help sdk for this device is available at http://www.3m.com/ssdcp/3M%20Swipe%20Readers/SDK/3M%20Swipe%20Reader%20SDK%201.2.1.2%20Setup.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OutputWedge>



    <InputModule name="Swipe">
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter name="LogLevel" value="1" />
            <Parameter name="LogFileName" value="SwipeOutputWedge.log" />
            <Parameter name="DateOfBirthFormat" value="%d-%m-%y"/>
            <Parameter name="ExpiryDateFormat" value="%d/%m/%y"/>
        </Parameters>
    </InputModule>

    <OutputModules>
        <OutputModule name="Keyboard" alias="keyb">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter name="DelayBetweenKeys" value="10" />
            </Parameters>
        </OutputModule>
    </OutputModules>

  <DataMerging>
    <DestDataItem name="General_DocumentNumber">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_DOC_NUMBER" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_DOC_NUMBER" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_LICENCENUMBER" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_FullName">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_FULLNAME" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_GivenNames">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_FORENAMES" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_FORENAMES" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_GIVENNAMES" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Surname">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_SURNAME" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_SURNAME" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_SURNAME" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Forename">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_FORENAME" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_FORENAME" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_FORENAME" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Forenames">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_FORENAMES" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_FORENAMES" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_MiddleName">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_MIDDLENAME" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_NameSuffix,">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_NAMESUFFIX" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_GivenNames,">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_GIVENNAMES" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_SecondName,">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_SECOND_NAME" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_SECOND_NAME" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Gender">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_SEX" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_SEX" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_SEX" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_GenderLetter">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_SHORT_SEX" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_SHORT_SEX" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_SHORTSEX" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_AddressStreet">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ADDRESS_STREET" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_AddressCity">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ADDRESS_CITY" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_AddressState">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ADDRESS_STATE" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_AddressPostalCode">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ADDRESS_POSTALCODE" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_AddressCountry">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_ISSUING_STATE" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ADDRESS_COUNTRY" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_IssuingState">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_ISSUING_STATE" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_ISSUING_STATE" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Nationality">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_NATIONALITY" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_NATIONALITY" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_OptionalData1">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_OPTIONAL_DATA_1" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_OPTIONAL_DATA_1" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_OptionalData2">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_OPTIONAL_DATA_2" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_OPTIONAL_DATA_2" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>

    <DestDataItem name="General_DateOfBirth">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_DATEOFBIRTH" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_IssueDate">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ISSUEDATE" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_ExpiryDate,">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_EXPIRY_DATE_STR," priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_EXPIRY_DATE_STR," priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_EXPIRYDATE" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>

    <DestDataItem name="General_DateOfBirthFormatted">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR_FORMATTED" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR_FORMATTED" priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_DATEOFBIRTH_FORMATTED" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_IssueDateFormatted">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_ISSUEDATE_FORMATTED" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_ExpiryDateFormatted">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_EXPIRY_DATE_STR_FORMATTED," priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_EXPIRY_DATE_STR_FORMATTED," priority="2" />
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_EXPIRYDATE_FORMATTED" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>

    <DestDataItem name="General_CodelineData">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_DATA" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_DATA" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Codeline1">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_LINE_1" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_LINE_1" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Codeline2">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_LINE_2" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_LINE_2" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Codeline3">
      <SrcDataItem name="CODELINE_LINE_3" priority="1" />
      <SrcDataItem name="SCDG1_CODELINE_LINE_3" priority="2" />
    </DestDataItem>

    <DestDataItem name="General_Height">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_HEIGHT" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Weight">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_WEIGHT" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Hair_Color">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_HAIR_COLOR" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>
    <DestDataItem name="General_Eye_Color">
      <SrcDataItem name="AAMVA_PARSED_EYE_COLOR" priority="1" />
    </DestDataItem>

  </DataMerging>

    <Script name="FIRST PAGE" startup="True">


        <!-- OCR Codeline Data -->
        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_FORENAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SECOND_NAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SURNAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SEX" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_TAB" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>  

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

    </Script>

  <Script name="SECOND PAGE">


        <!-- OCR Codeline Data -->
        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_FORENAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SECOND_NAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SURNAME" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_SEX" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_TAB" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>  

        <DataHandler name="CODELINE_DATE_OF_BIRTH_STR" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>

    </Script>

</OutputWedge>
```

How do i pause or freeze entering of data. Let's say after below code.. 
`<DataHandler name="CODELINE_SEX" storeAs="$data">
            <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
            <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
        </DataHandler>`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Please add a very specific question that we can answer.

Comment: How do i pause or freeze entering of data. Let's say after below code.. ```<DataHandler name="CODELINE_SEX" storeAs="$data">
   <Task name="keyb:TypeString" source="$data" />
   <Task name="keyb:PressSpecialKey" key="TAB" ctrl="False" alt="False" shift="False" />
  </DataHandler> ```